# How to automate disparate technology process in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation

I have a weekly process that I wish to automate in Azure. The overall process consists of about 5 distinct sub-processes. Total execution time is approximately 8  hours. The sub-process technologies include:

1. A third party data loader program that runs on a Windows VM in Azure. This program is able to send an email upon completion. This process then needs to trigger...
2. T-SQL scripts running on a Windows VM in Azure which upon completion needs to trigger...
3. SSIS jobs running on a Windows VM in Azure which upon completion needs to trigger...
4. A c# application that runs on a Windows VM in Azure which upon completion needs to trigger...
5. Python code running on a linux VM in Azure.

My question is: what Azure technology or technologies (e.g. automation runbook, logic app) could be used to stitch this thing together to give me back my weekend? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How much flexibility do you have to modify the VM's?  Are they in the same domain and accessible to each other in Azure?

Comment: Thank you. The VM's are all in Azure within the same domain and fully accessible to each other. They are running and I have no need to start or stop them.

Comment: I did not answer one of your questions. I have full control of the VM's and can modify them as needed.

Comment: Does #1 also support webhook, or only email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, sure, there's ways to automate the process using Azure.  I would choose **Logic Apps** because Business Process Automation is one of it's primary use cases.  But...*that's the easy part!*

The hard part for you is making these disparate apps accessible to outside services.  Running within Windows VM's, they don't have natural endpoints like native Azure Services.

There's lot's of ways to do this, depending on you ability to modify the VMs and programming skills.

Continued:  Since all the VM are in the same domain and network connected, the first thing would look at is a bit old school (new and shiny isn't always the best), **Windows Tasks**.  At least for 2-4.

Meaning, a Schedule Task on #2 can check for the email, then run its SQL, then start a Task on #3.

#3 can run it's jobs then start a task on #4 that runs the c# program.  Then #4 can trigger the Python script.  Your big gap then is how to trigger the Python script.  That could be as simple as FTP'ing a trigger file for task on #5 to see.

The Windows scripting can be done in PowerShell.  Not very elegant, but neither is your environment.

Finally, and almost the most important, you can use **Azure Monitor and a custom log** format to track the process.

Comment: I have full access to the VM's and can modify them as needed. Proficient in C#, Golang, Python, and JS. I can also hack around Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

This might be solvable with Durable Functions - and the External Events pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events

1. A timer-trigerded Function weekly kicks off an orchestrator Function
2. The orchestrator starts your VM (or a docker container etc.) that contains your data loader thing and injects a callback URL.
3. The orchestrator now waits for an external event (see link above)
4. The callback-URL points to another Azure Function that raises the event to continue the orchestrator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events#send-events
5. the orchestrator starts the next external task with the same pattern...